# Middle Mouse Button Click via Hotkey Modifier in OSX?

Tags: macos, hotkeys

If you can hold the **control** key and click to get a **right click**, is there another modifier key you can hold to get a **middle mouse button** click.  I don't think there is, so is there a way to create one?

Comment: What mouse do you use? Or do you have a trackpad?

Comment: I use Wacom or a trackpad in my MBP.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/):

[image]

You can add custom settings in [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). See the source for the [key and button constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true).

Comment: Now called Karabiner. (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)

Answer (score 3):

Command key+click will normally act as a middle mouse click. For example, Command+click a link in a web browser like Safari will act like a middle mouse click.

Comment: Command+Click will probably serve for most people, however it is not a "true middle click", in the sense that the app doesn't appear to be sent a middle click. I have used Karabiner to have fn+Click act as middle click as well as BetterTouchTool to get four finger tap act as middle click. (I could not get BTT to play nice with three finger drag and taps.)

Answer (score 1):

I often use [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) when I need to change anything with my mice for Mac OS X.

It allows to you set all sorts of bindings for the Magic Mouse, Magic Track Pad, or Mac Book Track Pad.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Option + Command + click` (note: this was using the Acme editor so there could have been some internal mapping)

Answer (score 0):

[Middle](https://middleclick.app) allows you to hold the fn key and left click for a middle click. It is a single-purpose app for adding the middle click to macOS for Magic Mouse and Apple trackpads. You can also pick from a few gestures for each device. (I'm the developer, and the app is not free)

[image: Middle app preferences]

Answer (score -1):

I use MiddleClick and it works well for me:
https://github.com/cl3m/MiddleClick (from github)

> Emulate a middleclick with triple tap on MacBook trackpad and Magic Mouse. Use private osx api for using the macbook multitouch trackpad code and some middleclick code.
>
> Not maintained anymore

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/726770)

Comment: @burgi so what do you want me to include exactly? The link contains the download link and I don't suppose there is a way to upload the file here.